# PHP Find difference between 2 arrays

Tags: php

I have 2 associative arrays thus :

```
$array1 = array('field1' => 'toast',
                'field2' => 'butter');

$array2 = array('field1' => 'toast',
                'field2' => 'margerine',
                'field3' => 'tea');
```

I want to find the names of the keys in array2 where the values are different from array1 or there is no matching key in array1 ie. 'field2' and 'field3' in this example.

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the PHP documentation?

Comment: Have a look at `array_diff_assoc` function.

Comment: [`array_diff_key()`](http://php.net/array_diff_key)

Comment: Wouldn't that result in only 'field3'? and not 'field2' and 'field3'?

Answer (score 3):

[`array_diff_assoc()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php) is what you are looking for:

```
$result = array_diff_assoc($array2, $array1);
var_dump($result);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  ["field2"]=>
  string(9) "margerine"
  ["field3"]=>
  string(3) "tea"
}
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/103184)